# Can't find exact api to get all products from ebay to sync with woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, ebay-api

I was planning to build a system where I can sync my product list on ebay to woocommerce and vice-versa.
I have gone through the internet searching this info, but cannot find the same. 
I have gone through the API: 
https://developer.ebay.com/docs#cat.
But, don't know which is going to work or even I don't know whether I'm searching the right category.
If you know any available plugin or any solution or sample, please refer.

Answer (score 0):

You COULD do it that way, in the same sense that you could build yourself a house if I sent you to a lumber yard.

I think what you're really after is this [here](https://woocommerce.com/products/amazon-ebay-integration/). It should do everything you need.

You still can do it using the link you shared, but give yourself a good 6 months at least to get your code written. (Or longer depending on how well you can code.)